# ANTLR Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, antlr, antlr3

What is the best strategy of making Abstract Syntax Trees serializable to an XML File?

Answer (score 1):

Chapter "ANTLR Trees vs. Custom Trees" on [this web page](http://www.bearcave.com/software/antlr/antlr_examples.html) shows an example of a antlr grammar, some input and the formatted output of the AST for the given input. The chapter contains a link to a C++ program to produce this formatted output.

It is not xml but pretty close and could be a good basis to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Walk the AST recursively starting at the root.

When descending to a node of type X, print an opening tag:

```
 <X>
```

then descend into children left-to-right and print their content.
After processing all the childen, print a closing tag:

```
 </X>
```

At a leaf node of type L, print

```
 <L value="abc"/>
```

with possibly attribute values of interest.

Done.

If you keep track of recursion nesting, you can print out the tag start and ends
with leading *recursion_depth* spaces, and follow with a newline.
Then your XML will be nicely nested.